# How let works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, let

I am bit confused how let works in javascript.

Case 1:

```
let x=5;
console.log(x);
```

//output:  5

Case 2:

```
if(true){
let x=5;
}
console.log(x);
```

//output: ReferenceError: x is not defined

Can anyone please explain how let works diffrently in these cases?

Comment: as far as i know its a temporary variable.. you can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Why so much duplicate inventation.

Comment: Let is used to provide block level scoping in javascript